# Creating a media menu items view attached to action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have put an action item on action bar, selecting which should open an option menu item view. It should be opened being attached to action bar.

[image: watsapp - attached to action bar]
[image: face book - on keyboard location]

I created an xml layout file.
Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/speak_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/speak_image" />

    </LinearLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I am trying to add that as subview of activity collection by setting dimention.
Contents:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
this.getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View optionview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_options_view, null, false);           

ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(200, 200); 
int actionBarHeight = actionBar.getHeight();
int actionBarWidth = 200;
params.setMargins(0, actionBarHeight, actionBarWidth, 200); optionview.setLayoutParams(params); optionview.requestLayout();

ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) this.getWindow().getDecorView();
root.addView(optionview);
```

But its not being shown correctly. It would be a great if I am suggested of how to create that UI element (menu option view) and how to attach after action bar are needed. I have attached screenshots of whatsapp and facebook, just would like get to understand what they are using (UI elements).

Comment: _But its not being shown correctly._ - an a example?

Comment: Sorry, which is not clear, my code or screenshots?